# How to Add configurable product in cart using product id in magento api

Tags: magento

I have creating webservices for my app but the problem id I am not been able to add configurable product in cart.Please find my code.Any help would be appreciated.

$customer_id = 'id_of_customer';

```
$cart_id = 'cart_id';        
$quantity = 'quantity';
$store_id = 1;
if ($cart_id != '' AND $customer_id != '') {        

    $arrProducts = array(array(
            "product_id" => '1887',
            "sku" => 'sku_of_product',
            "super_attribute" => array(151 => 3),
            "qty" => 2,
    ));

    $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cart_id, $arrProducts);
```

But I am getting the error Please specify the product's option(s).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
$product = array(
            'product_id' => 19,   // config product id
            'sku' => 'H001',
            'qty' => '1',

           'super_attribute' => array(
                0 => array(
                'key' => 92,        //attribute id
                'value' => 10       //value
                ),
                1 => array(
                'key' => 134,
                'value' => 3
                )
            )
        );  

$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($session,$cartId, array($product));
```